# How to open two files from command line, with both at the end of the file?

Tags: vim

I'd like to open two files from the shell in vim, laid out side-by-side, having both be scrolled to the end of the file.

As of now I can do

`vim -O "+ normal G $" file1 file2`

This does everything I want except have the second file be scrolled to the end.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
vim -c 'windo norm! G' -O file1 file2
```

`windo` will execute a command in every window. It has the side effect of making the last window the current window so this will make file2 the current window when you start vim.

In this case, if you really want to fix that, you can use

```
vim -c 'windo execute "norm! G" | winc h' -O file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
$ vim -O file1 file2 +windo\ norm\ G
```

Comment: even shorter: `$ vim -O file* +windo\ $`